# Force RabbitMQ stop receiving any messages

Tags: rabbitmq

How can we force RabbitMQ to stop receiving any messages for a certain time?

It must be fast as possible since we want to do that between tests.

We tried policies, but haven't found any that work for that question. Also rabbitmqctl stop and start would work but this is quite slow.

Background: We have an automated end to end test environment with RabbitMQ and lots of services. Between tests, we want to reset the environment with clearing all stores and caches and also the queues. Problem is, that in an intermediate state messages can populate data in an already cleared service. So we want to first stop RabbitMQ receiving messages, then clear all queues, then clear all stores and caches on all services.

Comment: stefku, how you have set **max-length-bytes** property? As I am getting error : <<"1">> is not a valid maximum length in bytes.

Comment: @Yuvarajsinh, maybe you try to send a string "1". But you have to send a number: "max-length-bytes": 1

Comment: Yes stefku, is was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the policy

```
max-length-bytes:   1
overflow:   reject-publish
```

for all Queues and Exchanges. That seemes to work, rabbit mq does not delivery any more messages.

Comment: Hi @Florian, while setting above policy, I am getting <<"1">> is not a valid maximum length in bytes.